# PostgreSQL: MD5 Authentication in pg_hba.conf gives me FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, authentication, psql

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and installed PostgreSQL 9.3.
Edited */etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf* as:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I restarted the server and now I'd like to login into postgres as **postgres**:

```
victor@workstation:~$ psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Shouldn't postgres prompt for my password, as I've set its authentication method to **MD5** ?

I understand that if I add **-h localhost** it will work.

Does not adding this flag causes psql to use peer-authentication?

Comment: You must have another `local ... peer` line above those.

Comment: Perfect... Why don't you answer it? I'll give you the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have another `local ... peer` line above those. The error `Peer authentication failed` comes from the *server*, and it's the server tha that picks the auth method.

Other possibilities would be:

- Didn't actually restart the server
- Edited the wrong `pg_hba.conf` file if there are multiple PostgreSQL instances on the system.

Comment: In fact there was another line before with "local ... peer" specific for the postgres user. As it was near some (many) commented lines, I didn't see.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open -> /etc/phppgadmin -> config.inc.php from your Terminal.

2) Find Below Line and Change it to False.

```
$conf['extra_login_security'] = true; to $conf['extra_login_security'] = false;
```

3) After changing Restart your Server.it will resolve your issue.

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```